Is it ethical for a university dean to be a full-fledged member of BNI?
I recently attended a networking event hosted by BNI (Business Network International) to explore opportunities outside academia. To my surprise, a dean from a prestigious university in my city not only participated but also claimed to be a founding member of the chapter.
For those unfamiliar, BNI operates on a referral system where members exchange business opportunities and recommendations—essentially a "you help me, I help you" approach. As someone with a European academic background, I found this troubling, as it could easily be perceived as nepotism.
This raises several ethical questions:
What value can a dean bring to a business-oriented network, and what could they gain in return?

I'm finding it hard to see any issue. Why do you think there is one? You seem to, as this is sort of a rant.

@Buffy it is NOT ethical that you as head of University help other company find business. At least in my book.

Hmmm. So definitely a rant.

This would be very unethical in Europe @buf

@Buffy do you think selling citation and authorship position is also rant and something not worth talk about? because this is same situation.

There is a real answerable question there, but your own concerns about potential ethical problems hides that question. I edited the question in the hope that it won't get closed.

You need to be more specific about why you think this constitutes "nepotism". I am from Europe and I do not see the supposed ethical problem here. It sounds to me like you are describing networking. Nepotism means: giving jobs or other opportunities to people based on personal kinship or friendship. I do not see how this is at all involved here.

@AdamPřenosil YES that is point of BNI, recommend job to your friend, and your network, t

@looktook I highly doubt that the purpose of BNI is to encourage personal friendships between its members. It seems like you are having trouble differentiating between "personal friends" and "a network of business contacts".

@AdamPřenosil they meet every WEEK. do you understand concept, they are very closely related and attand many activities. it is build on social theory and it is very troubling.

I'm no fan of capitalism, but you seem to be presuming that any recommendations are only based on being friends. Have you considered that people in businesses have actual knowledge about recommendations to make? For comparison, I refer people to papers and researchers all the time. Sometimes I'm friends with them, but that just means I know their work.

@AzorAhai-him- what kind of business you can bring to them?

@looktook Not business, but for me, academic information.

@AzorAhai-him- because you dont have what to offer business community, most academician DONT

What is distinct about a dean in this regard, as opposed to any other kind of organizational leader that has business-to-business interactions? A university is a business, too. Are you suggesting all types of business networking is unethical? Unclear why it would be more unethical for a dean to make productive business contacts than a CEO.

@NuclearHoagie you need to offer something in return, in BNI you have quotas, so he needs to bring business and profit to someone, how can dean do that?

What domain is this? Around here it’s not uncommon for faculty to maintain business relationships. The closer you are to engineering, the more important keeping up with industry is.

@looktook What?

@MisterMiyagi please put this into answer and collaborate. because for me it is so much wierd. im wierded out

@looktook Put what into an answer? I asked you what domain this is, that’s not an answer. If they are in engineering then the context for me asking is an answer (though your self-answer already categorically rules it out) but if they aren’t it’s just a random tangent.

@looktook The same way a CEO can, by buying goods and services from other companies. You seem to be asking how a dean can choose where to spend the university's money, which is a basic part of their job.

Networking with outsiders, who might make contributions to a Dean's college or might hire their graduates, seems highly appropriate. Any possible conflict of interest should be reviewed by the Dean's university. Relationships with the local community are often seen as desirable by universities.

I vote to close. The post reads as if BNI is a cult or secret society. If that's indeed the case (I know nothing about BNI), make that a part of the question: "Is it ethical for a university dean to be part of a cult?"

@WolfgangBangerth it is a cult!!! you need to bring something in the game to receive it.

@DavidSmith this is not simple networking, it is referral system. highly inappropriate.

@NuclearHoagie DEANS need to follow LAW on how to spend money and need to follow tenders, at least in Europe

Please don't edit a closed question to add your "answer", which continues the rant. You are in danger, here, of getting banned for a time.

@Buffy it appears people dont comprehend why is this unethical it si very troubling why they dont see it

@looktook If people don't understand what BNI is, then that is a problem with the question you asked.

There are legitimate reasons why the dean is part of such a network, for example:
A lot of research is funded by private companies. This differs considerably by discipline. So the benefit is that the university gets money and the funding company gets a particular bit of research done.
The companies are the providers of internships and are the future employers of students trained by that university. The university wants to place those students and the companies want to get access to next generation of employees.

sorry I missed the point, but who can Dean recommend? He needs to bring referrals, what kind of referrals dean can bring for business?

The answer says what the dean has to "offer" and what the university "gets" in return. What else do you need?

research in Europe is not a PROFIT rather expense, so it is not taxed as such or reported. so it doesnt have any sense

Please don't SHOUT. We Europeans find that rude....

not y experience on the conferences.

The profit is indirect. We (or at least I do) want our students to find good jobs when they are done. So a connection like that enables me to find them a good internship. While the company gets access to potentially good new employees. That is the profit both sides get from that.

BNI is based on direct profit @maarten'

BNI markets networks and makes money with that. That is not the same as you are saying.

Anyhow, since you are already convinced about your answer, there is no use in continuing this discussion.

you dont know what is BNI and how it function, so you are not aware why is not ethical, I wonder if someone in ethics would answer this question

@looktook I genuinely don't understand why you are even asking the question here if any response other than the one you want to see is dismissed. It's fine if your mind is already made up that this is a bad thing, but what were you hoping to achieve by asking the question on this website if your mind is already made up?

@AdamPřenosil i wanted to hear different perspectives, because this is not legal in Europe,
